# When multiply absolutely convergent seires and conditionally convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

Is this series absolutely converges
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_nU_n
$$
when

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n$ is absolutely convergent series and

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}U_n$ is conditionally convergent series?

Comment: Hi, try https://math.stackexchange.com (including what you have done)

Comment: Since $(U_n) \in c_0 \subset \ell^\infty$ the productseries converges absolutely,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this could be a considered a research level question: perhaps, this could be defined a <s>tricky</s> simple exercise. However, the answer is yes as I am going to show below

If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n$ is absolutely convergent, then we have that its [total variation as a sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#bv_sequences) is bounded, i. e.
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |C_n| <\infty \implies TV(C_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |C_{n+1} - C_n|<\infty
$$
since
$$
\infty >\sum_{n=1}^\infty |C_n|+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty |C_{n+1}|= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \big[|C_n|+ |C_{n+1}|\big]\ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty |C_{n+1} - C_n| \ge 0
$$
Now you can apply the *du Bois-Reymond - Dirichlet test* ([1], chapter X, §43 p. 315) and conclude the result you asked for.

**Addendum**

After the comment Dieter Kadelka, I noticed that his solution is even more straightforward and stronger. To explain it, note that the convergence of $\sum_{n=1} U_n$ (conditionally or not) implies $\lim_{n\to\infty} U_n= 0$ (i.e. $(U_n)_{n\in\Bbb N_+} \in c_0$) thus $(U_n)_{n\in\Bbb N_+}$ is bounded $\iff |U_n|\le M$ for all ${n\in\Bbb N_+}$ and a given $M>0$. his finally implies
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty U_n C_n\right|\le M \sum_{n=1}^\infty|C_n|
$$
and thus the product series converges absolutely.

**Reference**

[1] Konrad Knopp, *Theory and application of infinite series*, translated from the 2nd edition and revised in accordance with the fourth by R. C. H. Young. (English)
London-Glasgow: Blackie & Son, Ltd. XII, 563 p. (1951), [Zbl 0042.29203](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0042.29203).

Comment: Not so tricky, see @Dieter Kadelka's comment...

Comment: @abx thanks for opening my eyes. I was fooled by my current study a particular problem in summability theory.